# WCF RIA Exception on Invoke operation interrupts Caliburn.Micro coroutine execution?

Tags: wcf-ria-services, caliburn.micro

I am executing a series of Caliburn.Micro IResults by yield returning them from an IEnumerable method called by a Caliburn.Micro action message. The first IResult calls a WCF RIA service Invoke operation. Sometimes this operation fails and throws an exception. This is handled in the IResult where the InvokeOperation object is checked for error, I mark the error as handled and set the IResult's error message field to the error so I can recover it from the client.

The problem is that for some reason this interrupts the co-routine executing. I can't think of any good reason why, but when I'm in debug mode VS skips to the **server** code and bring up the unhandled exception helper telling me there was an uncaught exception (duh), and the co-routine never continues executing the other members of the IEnumerable.

Here is some of the code.

Called from the Action Message:

```
    public IEnumerable<IResult> Submit()
    {
        var register = new RegisterUserResult(Username, Password, Email, _userModel);
        yield return register;

        if (register.Success)
        {
            if (RegisterAsTrainer) 
                yield return new ApplyRoleToUserResult(Username, "Trainer", _userModel);
            yield return new NavigateResult(new Uri("/MainPageViewModel", UriKind.Relative));
        }
        else ErrorMessage = register.ErrorMessage;
    }
```

The code in the DomainService (which sometimes throws an exception)

```
    [Invoke]
    public void CreateUser(string username, string password, string email)
    {
        Membership.CreateUser(username, password, email);
    }
```

...where Membership is the ASP.NET class, which I am using for membership management.

The IResult that calls the above service (some details elided for clarity):

```
    public void Execute(ActionExecutionContext context)
    {
        ErrorMessage = null;
        Success = false;

        var ctx = new TrainingContext();
        ctx.CreateUser(_username, _password, _email, CreateUserCallback, null);
    }

    private void CreateUserCallback(InvokeOperation invokeOp)
    {
        if (invokeOp.HasError)
            invokeOp.MarkErrorAsHandled();

        Completed(this, new ResultCompletionEventArgs
            {
                Error = invokeOp.Error,WasCancelled = invokeOp.IsCanceled
            });
    }
```

The IResult.Completed **DOES** fire, but the rest of the method never executes. I'm literally tearing my hair out with this, please please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ugh I figured this out, stupid me. I was setting the IResult Error field, thinking I'd need to use that information later. I didn't know that having a non-null Error field would cause co-routine execution to halt (I thought only the Canceled field would do that). I'll leave this here in case anyone else runs into this issue.